# Elastic Beanstalk Application Version in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I attempted to manage my application versions in my terraform template by parameterising the name. This was an attempt to have a new application version created by our CI process whenever the contents of the application changed. This way in elasticbeanstalk i could keep a list of historic application versions so that i could roll back etc. This didnt work as the same application version was constantly updated and in effect i lost the history of all application versions.

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "default" {
   name        = "${var.eb-app-name}-${var.build-number}"
   application = "${var.eb-app-name}"
   description = "application version created by terraform"
   bucket      = "${aws_s3_bucket.default.id}"
   key         = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.default.id}"
}
```

I then tried to parameterise the logical resource reference name, but this isnt supported by terraform.

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "${var.build-number}" {
   name        = "${var.eb-app-name}-${var.build-number}"
   application = "${var.eb-app-name}"
   description = "application version created by terraform"
   bucket      = "${aws_s3_bucket.default.id}"
   key         = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.default.id}"
}
```

Currently my solution is to manage my application versions outside of terraform which is disappointing as there are other associated resources such as the S3 bucket and permissions to worry about.

Am i missing something?

Comment: My understanding is, `var.build-number` is unique, right? So the name `name        = "${var.eb-app-name}-${var.build-number}"
` will be unique as well. You can update and change it as an input variable.  Then you can control EB application version with it. So what's the real problem? Any details, please.

Comment: As i described, my aim is to create a new application version every time `${var.eb-app-name}-${var.build-number}` changes. i.e. every new build in our CI process. This isn't happening. We just constantly have a single application version that is updated with the new name and bundle. This means we cant roll back to a previous version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Terraform is concerned you are just updating a single EB application version resource there. If you wanted to keep the previous versions around then you might need to try and increment the count of resources that Terraform is managing.

Off the top of my head you could try something like this:

```
variable "builds" = {
  type = list
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "default" {
   count       = "${length(var.builds)}"
   name        = "${var.eb-app-name}-${element(builds, count.index)}"
   application = "${var.eb-app-name}"
   description = "application version created by terraform"
   bucket      = "${aws_s3_bucket.default.id}"
   key         = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.default.id}"
}
```

Then if you have a list of `builds` it should create a new application version for each build.

Of course that could be dynamic in that the variable could instead be a data source that returns a list of all your builds. If a data source doesn't exist for it already you could write a small script that is used as an [external data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html).

Comment: How would you use an S3 bucket data source to do this? All the version packages are in an S3 bucket. What would the syntax be to use that bucket as a data source for this?

Comment: You'd need to dynamically get the list of objects in the S3 bucket. Unfortunately you can't do that directly with Terraform but you could shell out with an external data source. It's probably worth asking in a separate question though and referring to this one in it