# How do I get a list of s3 objects with the aws_s3_bucket_object data source?

Tags: terraform

My specific problem is the same as [this guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741459/elastic-beanstalk-application-version-in-terraform), but I found his answer not detailed enough, also terraform has new features now that maybe can solve this better.

The problem is I'm using aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version to register beanstalk version, but terraform removes the old version before registering the new one. This is because aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version is replaced each time, what I need to do is generate a new one.

I'm attempting to do this with "count" and the aws_s3_bucket_object data source but I can't figure out how to get s3 objects as a list. I tried wildcards but that doesn't work:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "eb-bucket-data" {
  bucket = "mybucket"
  key = "*"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "default" {
  count       = "${length(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.eb-bucket-data.id)}"
  name        = "${element(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.eb-bucket-data.key, count.index)}"
  application = "myapp"
  bucket      = "mybucket"
  key        = "${element(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.eb-bucket-data.key, count.index)}"
}
```

Comment: Made this a feature request: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`aws_s3_bucket_object` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/s3_bucket_object.html) currently only returns a single item. You could iterate through a list of items but that puts you back to your initial problem of needing to find the list of items in the first place.

Short of creating a pull request for an `aws_s3_bucket_objects` data source that returns a list of objects (as with things like [`aws_availability_zone`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/availability_zone.html) and [`aws_availability_zones`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/availability_zones.html)) you can maybe achieve this through shelling out using the [`external` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html) and calling the AWS CLI.

An (untested) example for this might look something like this:

```
data "external" "bucket_objects" {
  program = ["aws", "s3", "ls", "mybucket", "|", "awk", "'{print", "$4}'", "|", "jq", "-R", "-s", "-c", "'split(\"\n\")'", "|", "jq", "'.[:-1]'"]
}
```

This runs

```
aws s3 ls mybucket | awk '{print $4}' | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")' | jq '.[:-1]'
```

which lists the objects in the bucket, takes just the filename elements, splits them into a JSON array using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) and then removes the trailing newline element from the JSON array because the `external` data source expects a valid JSON object to be returned.

You should then be able to access that with something like:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "default" {
  count       = "${length(data.external.bucket_objects.result)}"
  name        = "${data.external.bucket_objects.result[count.index]}"
  application = "myapp"
  bucket      = "mybucket"
  key         = "${data.external.bucket_objects.result[count.index]"
}
```

Comment: thats not very portable though, what if someone runs that somewhere that aws cli isn't installed? Will the data source return empty and tf will unregister all versions?

Comment: From memory I think it errors  the data source and then aborts the plan/apply but it's easy enough to test if you want to try.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Pull Request for this data source, `aws_s3_bucket_objects`:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/6968