# Terraform and Elastic Beanstalk versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I would like to deploy a local zip file to Elastic Beanstalk using Terraform. I would also like to keep old versions of the application in S3, with some retention policy, such as keep for 90 days. If I rebuild the bundle, I would like Terraform to detect this and deploy the new version. If the hash of the bundle hasn't changed then Terraform should not change anything.

Here is (some of) my config:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "application" {
  bucket = "test-elastic-beanstalk-bucket"
}

locals {
  user_interface_bundle_path = "${path.module}/../../build.zip"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "user_interface_latest" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.application.id
  key    = "user-interface-${filesha256(local.user_interface_bundle_path)}.zip"
  source = local.user_interface_bundle_path
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "user_interface" {
  name = "${var.environment}-user-interface-app"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "user_interface_latest" {
  name        = "user-interface-${filesha256(local.user_interface_bundle_path)}"
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.user_interface.name
  bucket      = aws_s3_bucket_object.user_interface_latest.bucket
  key         = aws_s3_bucket_object.user_interface_latest.key
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "user_interface" {
  name                = "${var.environment}-user-interface-env"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.user_interface.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.15.0 running Node.js"
  version_label       = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.user_interface_latest.name
}
```

The problem with this is that each time the hash of the bundle changes, it deletes the old object in S3.

**How can I get Terraform to create a new `aws_s3_bucket_object` and not delete the old one?**

---

This is related but I don't want to maintain build numbers [Elastic Beanstalk Application Version in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741459/elastic-beanstalk-application-version-in-terraform)

Comment: Can you enable bucket versioning? This way your old versions won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Marcin comment...

You should enable bucket versioning and add a lifecycle rule to delete versions older than 90 days
Here is an example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "application" {
  bucket = "test-elastic-beanstalk-bucket"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    id = "retention"

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      days = 90
    }
  }
}
```

You can see more examples in the documentation:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html#using-object-lifecycle

Then I would simplify your `aws_s3_bucket_object` since we have versioning we don't really need to do the `filesha256` just use the original name `build.zip` and good to go.

---

If you don't want to enable bucket versioning another way would be to use the AWS CLI to upload the file before you call terraform or do it in a local-exec from a `null_resource` here are a couple of examples:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html#interpreter-examples